# self.customView.backgroundColor assignment causes leak?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, retain

I'm working with creating my own custom view templates programmatically for the app I'm working on. To achieve this i have a custom view controller `MyVC` with a a custom view `myView` added on to it which is a property of `MyVC`. The class looks something like this:

```
MyVC.h   
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyVC : UIViewController{
MyCustomView *myView;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) MyCustomView *myView

@end
```

In the implementation i want to assign a background color to 'myView' and i do something like this in the viewDidLoad (after synthesizing my property of corse)

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
self.myView = [[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];

self.myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  

}
```

Now when i analyze my code i get a 'potential leak of an object' message when i assign the color. Is it because myView or the background color or both are being retained? 
In any case id like to know how this can be done correctly without potential leaks?

Comment: how do you initialize the myView?

Comment: I've overWritten the -(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame method in the 'MyCustomView' class. So i call that in viewDidLoad in my ViewController like so:
 self.myView = [[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't using ARC you should release over retained property:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
//allocate and initialize myView

self.myView = [[[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame] autorelease];
self.myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];  
}
```